# Node.js Cannot send script ?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this simple node.js server code  which sends `alert` :

```
var sys = require("sys"),
my_http = require("http");
my_http.createServer(function(request,response){

    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "application/javascript","Content-Length": "alert('');".length });
    response.write("alert('');");
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);
sys.puts("Server Running on 8080");
```

The server is up and running  :

[image]

and I do see the right headers for the response :

[image]

But the script is not executing  !

Also , The console shows :

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/javascript: "http://xxxx.com:8080/".

**Question :**

What am I missing and how can I make this alert work ?

Comment: But is that even possible? What's wrong with wrapping the script in `<script>` element?

Comment: `sys`?  what ancient version of Node are you running?

Comment: @Joe Is that really matter ? I use expressJs but for the simplcity I used that example.

Comment: Well, given how much node has changed in the 3.5 years since sys was deprecated, I'd say it's relevant even if it's still the same behavior in something more recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the browser to *execute* your JavaScript there has to be something to tells it that this is executable code (as opposed to text to be formatted & displayed.)

You can send your JavaScript inside an HTML document and use the `SCRIPT` tag for this as in the following example:

```
var sys = require("sys"),
my_http = require("http");
my_http.createServer(function(request,response){

    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html", });
    response.write("<html><body><script>alert('hello');</script></body>");
    response.end();
}).listen(8080);
sys.puts("Server Running on 8080");
```

Another approach is to fetch your JavaScript through another JavaScript program already on the browser (a-la AJAX) and have that other program execute it.

Answer (score 3):

For the script to execute by a browser, i'd rather use `Content-Type:html` & send

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('test');</script>
```

It's an old trick i used for "javascript streaming" before ajax existed.

For this to work, the browser has to know it is an an HTML document (or the "javascript url call" has to be initialiized from an exisiting HTML context)

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="your_js_node_url_here">
</body>
</html>
```

The you can stream any javascript for your_js_node_url , keeping an "always open" connection .

Of course , this is a bit "old school", but enables sort of  "code push" without websockets.

Comment: it doesnt work  - i dont see the alert. (Property 'alert' of object [object Object] is not a function )